# Android Studio / SDK: platform-tools (adb, fastboot) give segmentation fault (Gentoo Linux)

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, adb, gentoo, fastboot

I've tried both, the unofficial Gentoo ebuild of Android Studio from the mrueg overlay (android-studio-130.687321.ebuild) as well as the bundled package from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html (android-studio-bundle-130.737825-linux.tgz).

While both install fine and let me run Android Studio itself without any problems, adb (and also the fastboot utility) give me a segmentation fault, no matter if i start it with or without any arguments / parameters (such as "adb version").

I've tried deleting and reinstalling the platform-tools from within the Android-SDK-update-manager, but that also didn't help.

I've tried gdb, but to no avail since adb was built without debug symbols.

I'm running an up to date Gentoo ~amd64 and have used revdep-rebuild to make sure my system is consistent.

Any pointers welcome...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an official package from the tree: `dev-util/android-sdk-update-manager`. After installing it run

```
android
```

and install all you need through the GUI.

Also not sure, but before installing `dev-util/android-sdk-update-manager` try to remove `~/.android` folder.